# Open the send email dialog in outlook via C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, c#-4.0, outlook

My application has a requirement to open the send email window in outlook.

The application displays a list of invoices.  When the user clicks on an invoice number I need to open the send email window in outlook and attach the PDF statement.  The user can then modify the message and click send.

How can I accomplish this?

I have tried the following:

```
    using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

The application works fine on development environment but iam getting an exception:

```
**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))**

Detailed:

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
     at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
    at InvoiceSearchTool.Controllers.emailController.CreateMessageWithAttachment(String invoiceNumber, String recipient, String messageBody) in C:\Projects\KeleInvoice\InvoiceSearchTool\Controllers\emailController.cs:line 38
```

I do not have outlook installed on application server. do i need to istall outlook on server? or the exception is for some other reason? how to get rid of it?

EDIT: Adding Code

```
public static void CreateMessageWithAttachment(string invoiceNumber, string recipient, string messageBody )
    {
        try
        {

            Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MailItem email = (Outlook.MailItem)(oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));

            Models.DYNAMICS_EXTEntities _db = new Models.DYNAMICS_EXTEntities();

            #region set email recipients
            {
                ObjectParameter[] parameters = new ObjectParameter[1];
                parameters[0] = new ObjectParameter("InvoiceNumber", invoiceNumber);

                List<Models.EmailAddress> emailList = _db.ExecuteFunction<Models.EmailAddress>("uspGetEmailAddress", parameters).ToList<Models.EmailAddress>();
                if (emailList.Count() > 0)
                {
                    if(!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailList[0].Email.ToString().Trim()) ))
                    recipient = emailList[0].Email.ToString().Trim();
                    else
                        recipient = " ";
                }
                else
                    recipient = " ";

                email.Recipients.Add(recipient);
            }
            #endregion

            //email subject                 
            email.Subject = "Invoice # " + invoiceNumber;

            #region set email Text
            {
                Models.EmailText emailText = _db.ExecuteFunction<Models.EmailText>("uspEmailText").SingleOrDefault();

                messageBody = emailText.EmailTextLine1.ToString().Trim();
                email.Body = messageBody;
            }
            #endregion

            #region email attachment
            {
                string fileName = invoiceNumber.Trim();
                string filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/reports/");
                filePath = filePath + fileName + ".pdf";
                fileName += ".pdf";
                int iPosition = (int)email.Body.Length + 1;
                int iAttachType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
                Outlook.Attachment oAttach = email.Attachments.Add(filePath, iAttachType, iPosition, fileName);
            }
            #endregion

            email.Display();                

                        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            InvoiceSearchTool.Models.udtExceptionTable exception = new udtExceptionTable();
            exception.MethodName = "email";
            exception.Exception = e.ToString();
            exception.Date = DateTime.Now;
            DYNAMICS_EXTEntities db = new DYNAMICS_EXTEntities();
            db.AddToudtExceptionTables(exception);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }

    }
```

Comment: If you have the requirement to send emails via Outlook but don't have Outlook installed on the machine you send your emails from, what's the whole point of this? You need at least the COM objects that Interop references.

Comment: cant we just copy the dll in bin and use it like that?

Comment: Why do the emails have to be sent via Outlook?

Comment: @JP. : Just because, this is what i am assigned to!! I am a small fish, u know :)

Comment: @mini is it that you need to use Outlook or do you really just need them to be sent via the corporate Exchange server?  Exchange does have a SMTP interface you can use to send email.

Comment: FYI - Microsoft highly recommends that you do NOT use ANY of the Office applications in a web server environment.  The difference between a small fish and a big fish is that a small fish doesn't push back when the requirements are crap

Comment: @ChrisLively : Okay, the whole requiment is like this: the application is to list the invoice numbers, and when user clicks on the invoice number the pdf statement corresponding to the invoice number is attached to the email in outlook and outlook window only opens with all fields set(To, cc, subject, message body). The email is not sent. the user adds some custom message and den sends it. Can this be done with SMTP? Please help me to sort this. I need to design a web application which opens, outlook window on client machine.

Comment: I am adding my code here for bigger view.

Comment: @Mini: Okay the requirements you described is quite a bit different than your actual question.  I'll help reformat the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that we have your actual requirements, things get a little easier.

First off, get rid of Outlook from the mix.  You don't need it.

When the user clicks the invoice number, ask them for the message to go along with the email.  Once they type this in use the [standard .net smtp objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) to create the mail message, attach the pdf and send through your mail server.

You don't need Outlook installed on the server, nor do you need any type of interop.

If you are using Exchange or an IMAP server then the email will show up in the users outlook Sent box for you.

Comment: @ Chris: in this case, how can i be able to give user a preview of the attachment being sent?

Comment: @14578446: Well, you could have two links on the invoice line.  The first to see the invoice the second to send the invoice...

Answer (score 2):

you must have MS Outlook installed, COM Interop of Office applications relies on the Office apps to be there available, Microsoft still does want you to pay for your copy, is not giving you a library that replaces Word, Excel or Outlook.

Comment: does not mean it uses outlook. if the question was how to send email in C#, there are .NET Framework classes for SMTP email sending and nothing else is required, but he asks for using MS Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Microsoft COM Objects to send emails try looking at this MS Link 
it takes you thru a step by step approach. hopefully your machine will have the COM Objects as well ..

[Sending Outlook Emails via COM Object](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310263)